# combinational circuit interference

Tags: circuit-analysis

Hi I'm a complete newbie in EE, sorry if my question sounds dumb:

A combinational circuit hoas one input and one output. And it takes 1 second to generate one output.

If we put the first input into the circuit in the beginning, then we put the second  input into the circuit after 0.5 second.

- Will the first output's result be affected by the second input?
- Or will  there be no interference, we can get the correct first output after 1 second and also get the correct output after 1.5 second?

Because I'm completed new in EE, so I won't be able to understand technical EE analysis of circuit.

Comment: Hmm, you're skipping many steps for finding out this information. It's like asking how to land an airplane without ever having seen an airplane. If you try to land with wind against you then you will try to do X, if you try to land with wind from the side you will do Y. If your airplane is a jet plane you will do Z. There are hundreds of different parameters you are skipping (or ignoring) that will affect the answer. - Maybe it's better to start in the right end and learn what an airplane actually is. In other words, make an LED first light up and take it from there. - Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior depends on the delay time through all of the various paths from input to output. If there are some short delay paths and some long delay paths then the input must remain valid for the entire time that the combinational circuit is settling. However, if all of the delay paths have the same length then you can change the input value before the previous output has become valid. This is called **wave pipelining**. It's pretty difficult to do in practice, so we usually add registers in between the input and output in order to accomplish pipelining.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that help a lot, yes I was trying to understand pipeline CPU design

Comment: @amjad Welcome! Please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: A simple buffer , inverting , has no memory ( of the past) just a delay time.